# How to i set table header row with this java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i set first row of the table as thead with the following script?'''

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    /***************** Example on how to use the function ********************************/
    // The columns should all be names so that the script can split columns
    // Function getData() takes 2 parameters ( name of first column, name of last column)
      readData=getData("#","TOPSCORRER");
      for(var i=0; i<readData.length; i++){
          $("#data-table-default").append("<tr>");
          for(var j=0; j<readData[i].length; j++){
              $("#data-table-default tr").last().append("<td>"+readData[i][j]+"</td>");
          }
          $("#data-table-default").append("</tr>");
      }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript on button click:
- Creating a table 
- Creating a header and append it to the table 
- Creating a row and append it to the table 
- Apending the table to the body

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <button onClick="insertTable()">Insert Table</button>
  <script>
    function insertTable() {
      var table = document.createElement("table");

      /*INSERTING THE HEADER ROW*/
      var headerRow = table.insertRow(-1);
      var headerCell1 = document.createElement("TH");
      headerCell1.innerHTML = "Field1";
      headerRow.appendChild(headerCell1);
      var headerCell2 = document.createElement("TH");
      headerCell2.innerHTML = "Field2";
      headerRow.appendChild(headerCell2);
      var headerCell3 = document.createElement("TH");
      headerCell3.innerHTML = "Field3";
      headerRow.appendChild(headerCell3);

      /*INSERTING THE FIRST ROW*/
      var row = table.insertRow(-1);
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(-1);
      cell1.innerHTML = "Value1";
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(-1);
      cell2.innerHTML = "Value2";;
      var cell3 = row.insertCell(-1);
      cell3.innerHTML = "Value3";;

      document.body.appendChild(table);
    }
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The first row is when `i === 0` so just add the `thead` tags then.

```
  readData=getData("#","TOPSCORRER");
  for(var i=0; i<readData.length; i++){
      if (i === 0) { $("#data-table-default").append("<thead>"); }
      $("#data-table-default").append("<tr>");
      for(var j=0; j<readData[i].length; j++){
          $("#data-table-default tr").last().append("<td>"+readData[i][j]+"</td>");
      }
      $("#data-table-default").append("</tr>");
      if (i === 0) { $("#data-table-default").append("</thead>"); }
  }
```